# WebFlux Conditional FlatMap

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm relatively new to webflux and i want to find solution to avoid nested flatMap when there are conditionals:

I have 3 simple entities:

Item, Brand, Category.

Item basically contains: brandId and categoryId

```
public Mono<Item> patch(String itemId, PatchSpecs specs) {
return itemRepository.findById(itemId)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(..)))
        .flatMap(item -> {
            final String brandId = specs.getBrandId();
            if (brandId != null) {
                return brandService.getById(brandId)
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(..)))
                        .flatMap(brand -> {
                            final String categoryId = specs.getCategoryId();
                            if (categoryId != null) {
                               return categoryService.getById(categoryId)... -> return updateAndSave(..)
                            }
                            return updateAndSave(specs, item, brand, null);
                        });
            }
            else {
                final String categoryId = specs.getCategoryId();
                if (categoryId != null) {
                     return categoryService.getById(categoryId)... -> return updateAndSave(..)
                }
                return updateAndSave(specs, item, null, null);
            }

        });
}
```

How do I prevent this branching conditional flatMaps mess? I cannot imagine if i have another entity inside Item. There will be more nested flatMaps?

Comment: where is the product variable coming from?

Comment: sorry it was typo i meant item not product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your code well category and brand are optional attributes of the item. In this case I'd recommend the following:

```java
public Mono<Item> patch(String itemId, PatchSpecs specs)
{
    return itemRepository.findById(itemId)
                         .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can not find item.")))
                         .flatMap(item -> updateAndSave(specs, item));
}

private Mono<? extends Item> updateAndSave(PatchSpecs specs, Item item)
{
    Mono<Optional<Brand>> brand = getBrand(specs.getBrandId());
    Mono<Optional<Category>> category = getCategory(specs.getCategoryId());

    return Mono.zip(Mono.just(item), brand, category)
               .flatMap(tuple -> updateAndSave(specs, tuple));
}

private Mono<Optional<Brand>> getBrand(String inputBrandId)
{
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(inputBrandId)
               .flatMap(brandId -> brandService.getById(brandId)
                                               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can not find brand."))))
               .map(Optional::of)
               .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
}

private Mono<Optional<Category>> getCategory(String inputCategoryId)
{
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(inputCategoryId)
               .flatMap(brandId -> categoryService.getById(brandId)
                                                  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can not find brand."))))
               .map(Optional::of)
               .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
}

private Mono<Item> updateAndSave(PatchSpecs specs, Tuple3<Item, Optional<Brand>, Optional<Category>> tuple)
{
    Item item = tuple.getT1();
    Brand brand = tuple.getT2().orElse(null);
    Category category = tuple.getT3().orElse(null);

    // TODO do update and save here
    return null;
}
```

It will be more extensible this way and no need for duplication and nested conditionals. Please, verify it works as you expect.

Comment: It looks much better. I want to confirm if tuple.getT1() is non-blocking operation?  Will it work if, for example, we are using a list of categoryIds instead of just categoryId. Will tuple.getT3() work for Flux<Optional<Category>> ?

Comment: Yeah, tuple contains the result after it's arrived, so it's non-blocking.

Comment: If you have a Flux that might be a different question. You can use collectList operator in that case, but I should see the code for that to be sure.

Comment: can you zip a flux with a mono? would it only get the first element of the flux ?

Comment: If brandId is null, only categoryId is specified, the flatmap(tuple -> ..) never gets executed. What can be done here?

Comment: I read java doc on "zip" and i think that is the expected behavior: Aggregate given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, aggregating their values according to the provided combinator function. An error or empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively.

Comment: That's why I put it into an optional, so the Mono actually will never be empty, in worst case it will contain an empty optional and flatMap will always be executed (unless some error happens during querying}. You tested it and it's not working?

Comment: yes in my test if i specify brandId, it works just fine. But if brandId is not specified, then it just fails without error

Comment: That's interesting. Do you use the same code I shared including the optional stuff? I will take a look.

Comment: so not exactly same, i omitted defaultIfEmpty because switchIfEmpty was already there. Are those intentional?

Comment: Yee, they are. SwitchIfEmpty handles the case when we have an ID but the service could not find anything. DefaultIfEmpty is there to handle when the input ID is null.

Comment: It actually worked! Martin thx, but could you pls also show how you would do it if we have List<String> categoryIds instead of just categoryId?

Comment: Is the `List<String> categoryIds` coming from PathSpecs and you'd like to query all categories by those IDs and then save those categories with the item?

Comment: Yes it turns out it works the same way i just wrap it in Optional<List<Category>> Thx a bunch you're an angel

Comment: I'm glad it's solved. Just a note, if you have a list then Optional wrapping might be omitted.

Comment: oh why is it can you pls elaborate on this

Comment: Because List already has an empty state. And if you use collectList operator (I'm not sure if you do), then an empty flux will result in a mono with empty list.

Comment: awesome greats tips ! appreciate it